# SVG sprite animation not working when the file was exported by illustrator

Tags: html, css, svg, jquery-animate

The problem is with an SVG sprite file that I have created with Illustrator CC2020, my svg file doesn't work, but it works with other svg animation.

I think there is useless code in my SVG file (I have cleaned it with online tools), but the problem continues, any ideas.

My code with error animate:

```css
.emoji {
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image: url(http://promedia.tonohost.com/perfect-ani.svg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

.emoji::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%; /* keep the square ratio */
}

@keyframes moveX {
  to {
    background-position: right; /* you only need to move to right */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<div class="emoji" style="width:50px"></div>
```

Code working with svg sprite:

```css
.emoji {
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image: url(https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/style/images/wow-0a7ea725.svg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

.emoji::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%; /* keep the square ratio */
}

@keyframes moveX {
  to {
    background-position: right; /* you only need to move to right */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<div class="emoji" style="width:50px"></div>
```

Link Code SVG Error:

http://promedia.tonohost.com/perfect-ani.svg

Comment: in the first example the svg element it too height. Try changing the viewBox attribute to something like `viewBox="0 56 595.3 7"`

Comment: and do you have exactly 90 images in your SVG?

Comment: Well the primarry reason your demo here isn't working is because the browser shows an error fetching "perfect-ani.svg".  Chrome is showing "failed)net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".  There may be other faults, but until you fix this issue, we can't really help.  The SVG file loads via the URL directly, but not when used in this code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'm going to review the attributes of svg file.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau stackoverflow portal add automate httpS protocol for svg file.